# What happens on process termination?

Tags: exception, windows-ce

I have a Windows CE 5.0 device driver that protects some resources with critical sections. Threads from the client processes migrates to device.exe and enters and leaves this critical section. These Enter/Leaves can be hierarchically.

When one of my driver's client processes has more than one thread and

- one thread A has entered a critical section in the driver
- another thread B performs something (like division by zero) that terminates the process by an exception

what happens with the critical section. The driver DLL is loaded in the process device.exe and won't be unloaded.

But what happens to the the critical sections? Can other threads now enter? What happens with any resources the have been allocated by the thread A?

[Any pointer to a documentation is welcome.]

Comment: You need to implement a cancel routine so the OS can properly cancel any pending IRPs when the process terminates.  And so you can properly restore the state of your CS.  Not sure how much of this is applicable to CE: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/query/ff547093

Comment: Unfortunately Windows CE does not support overlapped I/O at all. Everywhere you would have to pass the pointer to an OVERLAPPED structure you have to pass NULL. The driver interface does not support the concept of a Cancel Routine. 
(http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms895459.aspx)